# Scope of Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [return from a function ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381804/return-from-a-function-ajax)
>   [JavaScript asynchronous return value / assignment with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779697/javascript-asynchronous-return-value-assignment-with-jquery)

How do you output the data variable to the second alert statement.

```
        $.post("index.ajax.php", { lookup:value }, 
        function(data) {
            alert(data)
            test = data;
        })
        alert(test)
```

Or would it be possible to do something like this?

```
function confirm_search(input) {
    $.post("index.ajax.php", { lookup:input }, 
    function(data) {
        $("#temp").val(data);
    })
}

var test = confirm_search(value);
alert(test);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

AJAX is asynchronous. The response is not available until *some time later*.

The `jQuery.post` call will *begin* the AJAX request, and return the jqXHR object which is handling the request.  The script will continue to be executed (`alert(test)` will fire next), and then *some time later* when the AJAX request has completed (i.e. the HTTP response is received), the callback:

```
function(data) {
    alert(data)
    test = data;
}
```

will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
var test;
$.post("index.ajax.php", { lookup:value }, 
    function(data) {
       alert(data)
       test = data;
})

function alertTest(){
  if(test != undefined) {   
    alert(test);
    clearInterval(t);
  }
}  

var t = setInterval(alertTest, 1000);
```

You will get test value when ajax request is completed and test is assigned

Answer (score 0):

If you are strict with scenerio, define test variable in global scope, in that way you can use it anywhere in your code.